# Blackberry ksoap2 request issues

Tags: soap, blackberry, ksoap2

First time posting a question. I'm trying to call some SOAP webservices from inside a blackberry app using the ksoap2 library. I've successfully managed to get a response from the one service, which uses an HTTP url, but now that I'm trying to get  response from a (different) HTTPS url, I've run up against a brick wall.
The response dump I'm getting has the following fault message:

"An error occurred while routing the message for element value : (country option I specified in my request). Keep-Alive and Close may not be set using this property. Parameter name: value."

The weird thing is that using Oxygen XML's SOAP tools with the XML request dump works just fine. Any ideas where to start looking? This has taken up a full day already.

Comment: Ok an update on this issue. I've discovered that setting
   
`connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");`

gives me a different error, namely "The SOAP action specified on the message, "x", does not match the action specified on the HttpRequestMessageProperty, x."

Comment: Have you checked the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update:

Responding to your comment below - it turns out [the double quoting is part of the SOAP spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383528). Some servers are more relaxed in their implementation, and will work without the quotes.

ksoap2 doesn't force the quotes onto your actions - you may want to patch your ksoap2 library to ensure the quotes are always there.

ymmv

---

### Original:

I don't think this is a SOAP related problem, nor with BlackBerry.

I think the problem lies on the server side, since that error string is not a common error (just google it to see no hits on the whole internet other than this question).

Looks like this is a job for the network guy on the server side to tell you what he's seeing on his end.

Only other thing I can think of is to make the call using HTTP instead of HTTPS. You can then use some network sniffer to see what the difference between the messages is. Alternatively, install an SSL proxy with something like "Charles" and sniff the packets like that.

Comment: Thank you Richard. Turns out the problem was that double quotes were missing on the SOAPAction header (even though SoapUI and Oxygen had no indication of this). Had to packet sniff the actual request to find that out.